# as3 - Customizing comboBox DropDown Menu Font and Color

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to change the font and font color of my ComboBox, and if possible also all the data that gets added to a List component (The text). I have this quick code which is very simple in modifying other components, but I can't find any this simple for combo Boxes and Lists.

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
        tf.color = 0xFFFFFF; 
        tf.font = "Segoe UI";
        StyleManager.setComponentStyle(Button, "textFormat", tf);
        StyleManager.setComponentStyle(CheckBox, "textFormat", tf);
        StyleManager.setComponentStyle(TextInput, "textFormat", tf);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for my own issue through a little more research time. Here is how I did it, for the List component I changed the font color and font type like so;

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
        tf.color = 0xFFFFFF; 
        tf.font = "Segoe UI";
        listName.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
```

And for the comboBox I used a CellRender class, which you can find anywhere on StackOverFlow with a little bit of research :)!